# How can i install "Stardict" on my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, dictionary

I tried to install Stardict on my macbook. but it didn't work

What have i tried?

I tried to follow this guide https://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/wiki/MacOSX but it didn't work for me or may be i did something wrong.

Who can install Stardict on mac machine, Can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: Can you add some details about the specific steps you did, what results/error messages you got and where things started to go wrong (and how)? Any detail may help.

Comment: So, Sorry my macbook now is on another place. but if you try and it's work you can tell me how do you install it? thank you.

Comment: You might have taken a wrong turn in following the instructions, so just answering with "I followed the instructions and it worked smoothly" won't help you that much. So please come back to share additional details.

Comment: Tried Version [3.0.5 beta1](https://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/downloads/detail?name=stardict-3.0.5-beta1-macosx.tar.bz2&can=2&q=) on 10.8.5 on a 2011 MBA, and it works (except the user interface is in .. Japanese?)

Comment: If your purpose is to get dictionaries, this site might help:  http://mysite.mweb.co.za/residents/clasqm/mac-os-x-dictionaries/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried this version  StarDict-3.0.1-MacOSX.zip   21.2 MB
it is in english

just upload dictionaries